# Entity framework Connection.Open connection.close

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

When i create a simple EntityFramework connection like this

```
Private Function ConnectEF() As ObjectContext
        Dim context1 As EstFarmacologicaEntities = New EstFarmacologicaEntities(tools.connectionstring("EstFarmacologica"))
        Return contexto1
End Function
```

Then i call the objectcontext ...

```
Public Function ListGroupFarma() As Ilist
        Dim context2 As EstFarmacologicaEntities = ConnectEF()
        Dim listFarma As IList = (From ... Where .. Select ...).ToList()
        context2.Dispose()
        Return listFarma
    End Function
```

Is it necessary to dispose the context1? as when using 'SqlConnection.Close' ...
i mean Context1 or its connection will remain in memory? how can i check that?

Answer (score 0):

`SqlConnection`s `Dispose` method calls its `Close` method internally. There is no `Close` method on `ObjectContext`.

If it implements `IDisposable`, dispose it properly, you never know what the author of that class included in their dispose method and could end up missing something if you try and do it yourself (like calling `.Close()` on `SqlConnection` in lieu of using a `Using` block).